# How to select all anchor tags with specific text

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

Given multiple anchor tags:

```
<a class="myclass" href="...">My Text</a>
```

How do I select the anchors matching the class and with some specific text. eg Select all anchors with the class:'myclass' and text:'My Text'

Answer (score 136, accepted):

```
$("a.myclass:contains('My Text')")
```

Comment: Thanks David. How do I do an exact match comparison rather than contains. I only want elements that match exactly.

Comment: I'd only add distinction between links and bookmarks: `​$('a.myclass[href]:contains("My Text")')​​​​`

Comment: @geoff: There's no built-in way to get an exact match.  You can either use the .each function to iterate through them all, or you can write your own jQuery selector.  Eric Martin has written a good one for exact match.  You can find it here: http://www.ericmmartin.com/creating-a-custom-jquery-selector/

Comment: What should be done if there isn't even a class to identify by?

Comment: @Amalgovinus I'm assuming you don't have an `id` to specify the anchor either?

Comment: @RadicalFanatic Right

Comment: than you for the answer but what if i want the exact value not all that contain the value ?

Comment: Contains will select all the elements which have even subset of the text

Answer (score 15):

You could create a custom selector similar to `:contains` for exact matches:

```
$.expr[':'].containsexactly = function(obj, index, meta, stack) 
{  
    return $(obj).text() === meta[3];
}; 

var myAs = $("a.myclass:containsexactly('My Text')");
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are only bothered if the anchor's text *contains* a particular string, go with @Dave Morton's solution. If, however, you want to *exactly* match a particular string, I would suggest something like this:

```
$.fn.textEquals = function(txt) {
    return $(this).text() == txt;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($("a").textEquals("Hello"));
    console.log($("a").textEquals("Hefllo"))
});

<a href="blah">Hello</a>
```

Slightly improved version (with a second *trim* parameter):

```
$.fn.textEquals = function(txt,trim) {
    var text = (trim) ? $.trim($(this).text()) : $(this).text();
    return text == txt;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log($("a.myclass").textEquals("Hello")); // true
    console.log($("a.anotherClass").textEquals("Foo", true)); // true
    console.log($("a.anotherClass").textEquals("Foo")); // false
});

<a class="myclass" href="blah">Hello</a>
<a class="anotherClass" href="blah">   Foo</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

First, select all tags containing 'MY text'. Then for each exact match, if it matches the condition do what ever you want to do.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a:contains('My Text')").each(function () {
        $store = $(this).text();

        if ($store == 'My Text') {
            //do Anything.....
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: First select all tags contains 'MY text'  then for exact match put it in if condition. then do what ever you want to do.

Comment: add this to your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the class of the desired object and just want to go after the link text it is possible to use

```
$(".myClass:contains('My Text')")
```

If you even don't know which element it is (e.g. a, p, link, ...) you can use

```
$(":contains('My Text')")
```

(just leaving the part before `:` blank.)

I have to add here that it brings up all elements beginning from `<html>`-Tag down to the desired element. A solution I could provide is adding `.last()` to it, but this one only works if there's only a single element to find. Maybe sbdy. knows a better solution here.

Actually, this should be an addition to the accepted answer, especially to @Amalgovinus question.

Answer (score -2):

I think this should work for the exact match thing..

```
$("a.myclass").html() == "your text"
```

Comment: Does not work.  `html()` only applies to the first element in the set of matched elements (http://api.jquery.com/html/).  You need control flow or iteration to go through each of the anchors, such as `each()`.