# Remove link if link name contains string

Tags: jquery

I've got a list of links on my page. Here's an example:

```
<a href="#">Link (tagMe)</a>
<a href="#">Link (anotherTag)</a>
<a href="#">Link (aThirdTag)</a>
```

How do I get jQuery to check all my links and remove the one with the string "(anotherTag)" so the output list will look like:

- Link (tagMe)
- Link (aThirdTag)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select all anchor tags with specific text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446936/how-to-select-all-anchor-tags-with-specific-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:contains` selector.

```
$('a:contains("anotherTag")').remove();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BbyWB/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function() {
    if($(this).text().match(/\(anotherTag\)/))
        $(this).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/wLM5q/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a:contains('anotherTag')").remove()
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pb8Mr/)