# Command to find a specifc text/link on a webpage, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, search, click, tampermonkey

Before I start, I'd like to point out I'm completely new to programming, so I hope my question isn't one that doesn't make sense at all and makes you guys rage. If it is, I'm very sorry, please enlighten me about it.

¨

I'm trying to make a script (in tampermonkey) that will look for a specific text/link on a webpage, and if that text is on the page, it will click on it.

For instance:
Let's imagine we refresh the page and sometimes a link called "Bob" appears. I do not know the target of "Bob", so just asking the script to redirect me to the target link isn't an option. I need something that actually clicks on "Bob". U get me? The problem here is I only know the name of the link, and nothing more. So I'd need a script which, first of all, looks for something called Bob, and secondly, clicks on it.

Thanks for helping,

--Bram

¨

PS: I'm completely new to programming, so if you decide to help me out (which I'd greatly appreciate <3) please explain it like I'm a total idiot/newbie. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of OP's previous question: [Click on specific links on a webpage with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738632/click-on-specific-links-on-a-webpage-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Just samples are below. Syntax can be wrong but they will give you an idea I think.

//Get all anchors

```
var anchors = $("a:contains('Bob')")
```

//Click it

```
$(anchors[0]).click();
```

And you can searc on stackoverflow look this links will help you;

[How to select all anchor tags with specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446936/how-to-select-all-anchor-tags-with-specific-text)

[How can I simulate an anchor click via jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery)