# How to disable a button, when there's other buttons with the same id?

Tags: javascript, html

So I made a [site](http://ShareCookie.com) for fun where anyone can post, kind of like a forum. As of now, I am working on a report button, to obviously report posts. I would like the button to be disabled after the user clicks it, to prevent extra reports in the current session. Here is my code:

```
{{#each posts}}
  <p><font color="black" size=5><b>{{title}} - </b></font><br>
  <font size=5 color="gray"><i>by {{author}}</i></font></p>
  <p><font color="black" size="4">{{content}}</font></p><br>
  <a id="hides" onclick="hidefunction();"><font size=4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert" aria-hidden="true"></span></font></a><br>
  <font color="black">_______________________________________________________________________</font>
{{/each}}
```

I know the code is pretty unsightly, but it works. That code pulls all the posts from my database, and creates a post on the site with the information. Along with the post, it makes a report button (the glyphicon). As you can see, the report button's `id` is `"hides"`, and `onclick` calls the `hidefunction()` shown here:

```
<script>
 function hidefunction(){
  document.getElementById("hides").setAttribute("class", "disabledl");
 };
</script>
```

So, as you can see, it sets the attribute of `hides` to my hidden `class`, but as I guessed, this only hides the button on the first (most recent) post. Even if I click a different report button. Is there some way to give each button a unique `id`? So that I can hide the correct button, instead of it just hiding the most recent button created. Thanks!

Comment: It only works on the first button, because ID's are **unique**, there can't be two buttons with the same ID.

Comment: You cannot declare multiple elements with same id.

Comment: and disabledl => disabled

Comment: @Jeremy `disabledl` is a CSS class, and so that may not be a typo.

Comment: I pretty much understood that. But is there some way to give each button a unique id when they are created?

Comment: `disabledl` is the name of my class haha :)

Comment: @krillgar, dec0mpiled: right, i'm to used jQuery, dont use class for that, my mistake

Comment: Up to what time do you want that button to be disabled ?

Comment: The font element has been deprecated since HTML 3. Use spans and classes instead. Element IDs need to be unique that is why you can't reference more than the first id

Answer (score 5):

The problem that you're having (as mentioned immediately in the comments) is that IDs **MUST** be unique on a webpage. If they aren't, it's *usually* the first element that gets chosen, but that still may not be correct.

However, you can get around this and not have to change anything (though you should find a way to make all IDs unique).

Because of the way JavaScript works, you already have a reference to the element that was clicked inside that event with the `this` keyword.

```
<script>
    function hidefunction(){
        this.setAttribute("class", "disabledl");
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the button via JavaScript, so that each button has its own ID.

```
 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
    var t = document.createTextNode("This is the button.");       // Create a text node
    btn.appendChild(t);                                // Append the text to <button>
var a  = Math.Random()*100;
btn.id = "Button" + a; //add unique id.
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Now, you may want to store the ids in an array for later use.

This can be done by making an array, named idstore:

```
var idstore = [];
```

and then pushing the random number generated everytime to the array:

```
idstore.push("button"+a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your IDs unique as well they are UNIQUE by their very nature. If they are not unique they you will have problems like this. As to disabling a button there are a number of approaches you can take. One of the best most reliable way to do this is to have a var that the onclick function checks before it runs the main body of its code to ensure it is enabled.

```
  val enabled = false;
  function onClickFunc() {
    if (!enabled) {
      return
    }
    //... do something
  }
```

Aside from that you can make whatever code that controls the enabled var also apply css to the button to make it appear disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Implement [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com). (Or your framework of choice)

Then you can select an element based on its text as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446936/how-to-select-all-anchor-tags-with-specific-text). The code would look similar to this:

```
$("#myid:contains('My Text')")
```

You'd probably be a lot better off switching them to unique IDs and a common css class, which would open up tremendous power using a framework.