# How to target a <th> which contains only specific text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running this and it works:

```
$wikiDOM.find(".infobox th:contains('Date')")
```

However, that could also be `Date of birth` while instead I need to target only those onse with the string `Date` only.

**UPDATE**

Full case:

```
if ($wikiDOM.find(".infobox th:contains('Location')").length > 0 && $wikiDOM.find(".infobox th:contains('Date')").length > 0) {
  $('#results').append('<li>' + curTitle + "<br>" + $wikiDOM.find('.infobox th:contains("Location")').siblings('td').text() + '<br>' + $wikiDOM.find('.infobox th:contains("Date")').siblings('td').text() + '</li>');
}
```

Tried:

```
$.fn.textEquals = function(txt) {
  return $(this).text() == txt;
}
if ($wikiDOM.find(".infobox th").textEquals('Location') && $wikiDOM.find(".infobox th").textEquals('Date')) {
  $('#results').append('<li>' + curTitle + "<br>" + $wikiDOM.find('.infobox th:contains("Location")').siblings('td').text() + '<br>' + $wikiDOM.find('.infobox th:contains("Date")').siblings('td').text() + '</li>');
}
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: Use `$wikiDOM.find('.infobox th').filter(...)` with some filter function suitable for checking the text content.

Comment: @Bhargav there isn't much more to add to that in regards of the question, however I believe I have found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2447117/7790433

Comment: @Bhargav update with full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [JQuery's filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
$(".infobox th").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === "Date";
})
```

Your code could be refactored to something like (not tested):

```
function doSelect(text) {
    return $wikiDOM(".infobox th").filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === text;
    })
}

if (doSelect('Location').length > 0 && doSelect('Date').length > 0) {
  $('#results').append('<li>' + curTitle + "<br>" + doSelect("Location").siblings('td').text() + '<br>' + doSelect("Date").siblings('td').text() + '</li>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>test1</th>
  <th>test2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>

    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is your jquery

```
//I have tested below line and it worked
//$('th:contains("test1")').css('color', 'red') 

var myth = $('th:contains("test1")'); //here is your th
```

Comment: yea ok, just as per my question, the text is test1 and test2 not only test

Answer (score 0):

You can use .text() to return the string value of an element and run your conditional like that:

Html example:

```
<th>My Text</th>
<th>My other Text</th>
```

jquery example:

```
$('th').each(function()
{
    if ($(this).text() === 'My Text') {
        //do something
    }
})
```

this will loop through all th elements then run the if statement on the text values. Information can be found for each function here:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

http://api.jquery.com/text/